# Flask api variable column

Tags: python, json, flask

I am writing an API using [flask](/questions/tagged/flask).

I would like the API to return either the elements in the category column or in the subcategory column depending on the [url](/questions/tagged/url).

For instance: `/categories/subcategory` or `/categories/category`.

I have tried to create the variable `category_type` and assigned it to the output `d` but it didn't work. I'm getting the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'Categories' object has no attribute 'category_type'

Here's my code:

```
 class Categories(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'categories'
      category = db.Column(db.Text)
      subcategory = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key = True)

    @app.route('/categories/<string:category_type>', methods=['GET'])
    def categories(category_type):
      if request.method == 'GET':
        results = Categories.query.all()

        json_results = []
        for result in results:
          d = {'Category': result.category_type,
                          }
          json_results.append(d)

        return jsonify(items=json_results)
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: good point I have edited the post with error message

Answer (score 0):

Your `Categories` model doesn't have a field called `category_type`. See the last line this snip of your loop:

```
results = Categories.query.all()
json_results = []
for result in results:
    d = {'Category': result.category_type}
```